# How to automate the installation of an .rpm file in Linux

Tags: linux

So I have 50 servers and they all need to have an .rpm file installed on them. The install is as simple as this...

1. rpm -ivh https://localserver.com/app55.rpm
2. /opt/app55/app5 -32
3. systemctl enable app55

And that's it. My question is, how best can I script/automate this? Should I create some sort of file that kicks off all three steps in order and log in to each server run that file? Or, how hard would it be to write a script that connects remotely to each server and runs these three commands?

I manually performed the steps to confirm the time it takes and the simplicity. It's very simple, but 50 times is a lot, besides, I'd like to learn how to do this. I tried creating an install.sh and simply putting the three commands there on the first three lines however, I could not get it to run.

Comment: A shell script is nothing more than a collection of commands you could enter on the command line. If those are the 3 commands you need executed. Create a new text file. Put `#!/bin/sh` at the top, then put each of those commands inside and save the file. Now you can run it with `sh thefileyousaved` or to make it executable, set the execute permission bit with `chmod +x thefileyousaved` and now simply `./thefileyousaved`.  (there are many was to improve upon that as you learn more about scripting). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest using [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible). It is a little steep learning curve to start with but it will pay off in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

its time to use Ansible, prepare your inventory {50nodes}
prepare your yaml and load it on the shell with command : ansible-playbook -i my.yml inventory.ini

Good luck !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).